# Obtener usuario en sesión con spring security

Tags: java, jsf, spring, xhtml, spring-security

Tengo una aplicación web y que utiliza spring security y todo funciona perfectamente, puedo iniciar y cerrar sessión, sin embargo lo que quiero hacer es obtener el objeto usuario que está en sesión desde un bean de jsf.

Esta es mi configuración de spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
SystemUserDetailService systemUserService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //Para visualización de Consola de H2
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    //CSRF es manejado por JSF
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml");
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.xhtml").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/operacion/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "OPERADOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/clientes/forma.xhtml").hasAnyRole("VENTAS", "ADMIN", "SERVICIO","OPERADOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/clientes/alias.xhtml").hasAnyRole("VENTAS", "ADMIN", "SERVICIO","OPERADOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/clientes/descuentos.xhtml").hasAnyRole("VENTAS", "ADMIN", "SERVICIO","OPERADOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/usuarios/consultar.xhtml").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","OPERADOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("VENTAS", "ADMIN", "SERVICIO", "OPERADOR")

            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/menuPrincipal.xhtml").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied.xhtml");

}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(systemUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}

/**
 * We want to ignore all public resource files from the security filter,
 * otherwise it will deny cache on the client side
 *
 * @param web web security object
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/javax.faces.resource/**");
}

@Bean
public HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository httpSessionSecurityContextRepository() {
    return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
}

/**
 * In case session expires, JSF must AJAX-redirect to the login page
 *
 * @return session management filter
 */
@Bean
public SessionManagementFilter sessionManagementFilter() {
    SessionManagementFilter filter = new SessionManagementFilter(httpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
    JSFRedirectStrategy strategy = new JSFRedirectStrategy();
    strategy.setInvalidSessionUrl("/login.xhtml");

    filter.setInvalidSessionStrategy(strategy);
    return filter;
}

}
```

Esté es mi bean :

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class SessionCtrl {

private Linea linea;
private int indiceMenu;
private Usuario usuario;

public SessionCtrl() {
    linea = new Linea();
    indiceMenu=0;
    usuario = null//Aquí es donde quiero obtener el usuario de la sessión de spring;
}

public void seleccionarLinea(Linea linea) {
    this.linea = linea;
}

public Linea getLinea() {
    return linea;
}

public void setLinea(Linea linea) {
    this.linea = linea;
}

public int getIndiceMenu() {
    HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String url = origRequest.getRequestURL().toString();

    if (url.contains("/admin/")) {
        indiceMenu = 0;
    }

    if (url.contains("/operacion/")) {
        indiceMenu = 1;
    }

    return indiceMenu;
}

public void setIndiceMenu(int indiceMenu) {
    this.indiceMenu = indiceMenu;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví utilizando el objeto Authentication de Spring e inicializé el objeto en un postconstructor de la siguiente forma :

```
@Autowired
UsuarioService usuarioService;

private Linea linea;
private int indiceMenu;
private Usuario usuario;

public SessionCtrl() {
    linea = new Linea();
    indiceMenu = 0;
    usuario = new Usuario();
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
    usuario = this.usuarioService.getUsuarioByCorreo(userDetail.getUsername());
    System.out.println(usuario);
    System.out.println(usuario.getNombre());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

espero sirva a alguien mas. yo lo obtengo asi:

```
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    UserDetails userDetails = null ;
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    String userName = userDetails.getUsername();
```

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras un poco cómo ese código resuelve el problema. Haz una lectura de [answer] y consulta [help] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.